# can I reschedule the kernel tasks ?

Tags: mac-mini

Two questions.

1. Can someone tell me who the idiot was who decided that the best time to have a 'kernel task' running (which I'm guessing is SpotLight indexing) was at 6 o'clock in the evening, when so many Mac owners would be getting home from work and settling down to use their Mac?  Because CPU usage at 800% and a thirty-second lag before the system deigns to respond to mouse clicks, is just the best thing ever.
2. Is there a way to force the Mac to carry out this task at 2 AM?

Thanks.

Comment: While it is an annoying situation I am sure, could you please rephrase your question to respect the community rules: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 4):

Your assumptions are off on multiple points.

First off, kernel_task is not Spotlight indexing.

Secondly it is not a task that is scheduled to run at a specific time.

kernel_task is really just an umbrella-process for everything happening with the operating system kernel:

For example running programs (called processes) ask the kernel to do stuff for it via so called system calls (i.e. asking for data from a file, sending data over the network, etc.). The time the kernel spends on handling this is attributed to the kernel_task.

The kernel_task also has threads doing internal housekeeping for the kernel that is not dependent on system calls from processes. This is for example the scheduling of processes (i.e. which program to run next), paging (swapping, etc), thread reaping, etc.

Lastly the kernel also has special functionality to ensure that CPUs are *not* doing anything. This could be done to lower CPU temperature, save power or put the system in a state ready for sleep (i.e. when closing the lid on a laptop). Here the kernel_task when viewed from Activity Monitor or similar will look like it is using the CPU fully, but really it is using it fully to say that it shouldn't do anything (i.e. the CPU should be in an idle state, preferably in a lower power level).

To sum it up, your request to delay this processing to 2 AM doesn't make sense, unless you want to delay the execution of all your other programs as well.